# Opencv matchTemplate fails to detect similar objects

Tags: python, opencv, matchtemplate

I'm using OpenCV 4.5.4 to locate an image in another image. And for that the matchTemplate function.

The task is to find "Chips" on a table, for a robot to sort them into magazines for automated production. There is only one type of "Chips" on the table, but aound the half of them is flipped so the robot will sort them in 2 magazines and flip the one for the next production step. Not all chips must be detected in one step as they overlap alot. The robot can sort out the detected ones and come back to its resting position to make a new photo.

Example Scene:
[Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNsCK.png)

For the golden side of the chips its quite working well

Template: [object_a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYuxF.png)

Result: [result_obj_a_0_5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAzCM.jpg)

but when i use the template for the other side, i get just very few right detection and when decreasing the matching threshold, it false detects the metal table prior to the objects.

Template: [object_b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcxgh.png)

Result threshold 0.5: [result_obj_b_0_5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9eB4.jpg)

Result threshold 0.4: [result_obj_b_0_4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwDVN.jpg)

Both Templates where cutted from the scene image and just rotated to get proper detection boxes.

My code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def rotate_image(image, angle):
  image_center = tuple(np.array(image.shape[1::-1]) / 2)
  rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle, 1.0)
  result = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, image.shape[1::-1], flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
  return result

def draw_box(img, pt0, pt1, pt2, pt3, color=(0,255,0), thickness=2):
    cv2.line(img, (int(pt0[0]), int(pt0[1])), (int(pt1[0]), int(pt1[1])), color, thickness)
    cv2.line(img, (int(pt1[0]), int(pt1[1])), (int(pt2[0]), int(pt2[1])), color, thickness)
    cv2.line(img, (int(pt2[0]), int(pt2[1])), (int(pt3[0]), int(pt3[1])), color, thickness)
    cv2.line(img, (int(pt3[0]), int(pt3[1])), (int(pt0[0]), int(pt0[1])), color, thickness)

def rotated_coord(rotation_center, angle, points):
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(rotation_center, angle, 1.0)
    points = np.array(points)
    ones = np.ones(shape=(len(points),1))
    points_ones = np.concatenate((points,ones), axis=1)
    transformed_pts = M.dot(points_ones.T).T
    return transformed_pts

scene = cv2.imread('scene.png')
template = cv2.imread('object_b.png')
result = scene.copy()

h, w, c = template.shape
step = 5
for i in range(step,360+step,step):
    step_img = rotate_image(scene, i)

    res = cv2.matchTemplate(step_img,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    threshold = 0.5
    loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        pt0, pt1, pt2, pt3 = pt, (pt[0], pt[1] +h), (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (pt[0] + w, pt[1])
        draw_box(step_img, pt0, pt1, pt2, pt3)
        pt0, pt1, pt2, pt3 = rotated_coord(tuple(np.array(scene.shape[1::-1]) / 2), -i, [pt0, pt1, pt2, pt3])
        draw_box(result, pt0, pt1, pt2, pt3)
    cv2.imshow('Result',np.hstack((step_img, result)))
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    
cv2.waitKey()
```

Above code is just a working example to demonstrate the problem. I improved the code to filter duplicate detections and display the rotational axis of the found boxes.

Example [refined_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TSvR.jpg)

As im quite unfamilar with the matchTemplate function, my question is is there a way to improve the detection rate. Im thankful for any help.

Comment: See non-maxima suppression etc at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2021/03/29/multi-template-matching-with-opencv/

Comment: matchtemplate can't find rotated instances, or even scaled instances. it can only find translated (moved) instances. wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @fmw42 As i understand it, non-maxima-suppression is for filtering boxes, that cover the same area, not for detecting more boxes, right? So thanks for pointing that out, but did not answer the question.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz i know that matchtemplate cant find rotated or scaled Instances. But as you see in my images, the objects are all the same size. And as you see in the code i rotate the scene around 360 degrees to detect the objects in any angle, you may have a look at the images.